# Copy/paste and drag&drop not working in VMware machine with Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, vmware, vmware-tools

Suddenly copy/paste stopped working from/to Windows 8 host computer to/from ubuntu virtual machine. Ubuntu restart did not help. I tried command:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

But got report I have newest version. Guest Isolation settings are enabled. What could be the scenario of fixing this problem?

Comment: Note that this is a known issue - there's an issued with shared files not working in a Linux VM, and it seems similar components of that don't work with VMware at this time.

Comment: Solution here: https://superuser.com/a/1323289/347416

Comment: I noticed this problem has to do with me using a different window manager.  VM shared clipboard works fine using gdm3, but when I switched to DWM shared desktop no longer worked

Answer (score 84):

I had the same problem and found that this can be fixed by executing the following commands:

1. `sudo apt-get autoremove open-vm-tools`
2. Install VMware Tools by following the usual method (`Virtual Machine
   --> Reinstall VMWare Tools`)
3. Reboot the VM
4. `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop`
5. Reboot the VM, after the reboot copy/paste and drag/drop will work!

Comment: I found I didn't need to install VMware Tools. Doing an apt-get of open-vm-tools, then open-vm-tools-desktop, and then restarting worked for me.

Comment: Did not work for me on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit.

Comment: Didn't work for me either on 16.04 64 bit (server)

Comment: Working on Xubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop. Thanks!

Comment: Removing open-vm-tools and rebooting destroyed my kernel and I had to reinstall the OS from scratch.

Comment: This worked I have ignored the error "script still running ... while rebooting

Comment: I had this copy/paste problem with a Windows VM (although only with copy/paste - the drag-and-drop of files worked) and this solution solved the problem.

Comment: This worked to get full screen functionality back for me.  Answer by Charles Green worked to get copy-paste functionality back.

Comment: Did nothing for me on Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: This worked for me using Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Works flawlessly under Linux Mint 19.1 (July 2019) Thank you so much!

Comment: For me, it worked without having step #4 executed.

Comment: I just did 

```
sudo apt-get autoremove open-vm-tools
reboot
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

any copy paste clipboard/files started to work

Comment: did not work on ubunto server 20 on vmware

Comment: Works with Ubuntu 20.04 and VMWare workstation 16 pro

Comment: I just did "sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop" and restarted the guest. Copy-and-paste and drag-and-drop now work between host and guest! I have VMware Workstation 16 on Windows 10 host running Linux Mint 19.3 (Ubuntu 18) guest.

Comment: Hi read the comment of @srgstm, but I have the same configuration of him (VMware Workstation 16 on Windows 10), but running Debian 11.x and it doesn't work. I tried also other suggestions here, but nothing.

Comment: Not working in Ubuntu 20. Also there is no " Reinstall VMWare Tools" option for me in VMWARE

Comment: No need to reboot, just run `vmware-user`.

Answer (score 69):

I tried the approach suggested by solution101 above, but it didn't work for me. This is how I solved the problem:

1. Open Terminal
2. `sudo apt install open-vm-tools-desktop`
3. restart the guest operating system

This seems to have fixed the copy-and-paste issue for me.

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 17.04 running on a macOS Sierra host - thanks!

Comment: Worked on Windows 7 / VMware Player - Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 18.04. I had missed `open-vm-tools-desktop`.

Comment: you only need to do `open-vm-tools-desktop` because that installs `open-vm-tools` automagically

Comment: @218, can u please update your answer per JREAM's comment ? thanks

Comment: This worked for me with VMware Fusion Pro 12.2.3. Host OS: Mac OSX 11.7.2. Guest OS: Kali rolling.

Comment: worked on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 16):

This is copied verbatim from a [vmware community forum](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/436411?start=15&tstart=0):

1. Go into VM / Settings / Options / Guest Isolation
2. UNCHECK bothcheckboxes (Enable drag and drop, Enable copy and paste) and click OK.
3. Shut down the guest, and shut down VMware Workstation
4. Reboot the host computer
5. Run VMware Workstation but do not launch the guest yet.
6. Go into VM / Settings / Options / Guest Isolation for the guest, and
7. CHECK both checkboxes
8. Power On the guest.

Comment: I don't have this **Guest Isolation** option

Comment: @AlaaM. Perhaps they have removed the feature?  I no longer run VMWare, but instead am using KVM/QEMU for virtual machines.

Comment: Maybe. But it's ok looks like i just had to `sudo nautilus` and then i could drag and drop

Comment: Did nothing for me on Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 17.04 32-bit. I just did step: 1,2,3,[no 4],5,6,7,8 ~ the paste works now

Comment: This worked for me using VMware Workstation 14

Comment: Guest Isolation is available on pro version (was called workstation).

Comment: There resulted in absolutely no working copy and paste. Stack Exchange's perfect record of never providing a single working solution to any problem I've ever had with linux stands unbroken!

Comment: This worked for me on 1804.

Answer (score 16):

The best and working solution is restarting your VMWare application (Workstation, Fusion, etc.), not the VM itself. (provided, of course, that you have installed the VMWare tools already.)

Comment: This simple answer is what worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple! didnt even need to reboot my host.

Comment: In my case I also needed to restart the VMWare Workstation Server service (vmware-hostd.exe process). Just restarting VMWare application was not enough.

Comment: Restarting the guest machine, and VMware, and the machine VMware is running on accomplished... drum roll please... ABSOLUTELY NOTHING TO FIX THE PROBLEM! Why am I not even remotely surprised?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, somehow the guest start-up job running the VMware User Agent was removed from my xfce session autostart. 
You need to run `/usr/bin/vmware-user-suid-wrapper` at login

Comment: Same with KDE 5.25. It worked fine in KDE 5.24, but now this needs to be manually run at startup it seems. Unfortunately just running it via KDE's autostart doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: running `/usr/bin/vmware-user-suid-wrapper`  worked for me after trying @Charles Green (worked for me before but not this time)

Comment: Nope. Ran it, confirmed running, still no working copy & paste.

Answer (score 4):

You *can't* uncheck the checkboxes while the VM is running; they are disabled. If you do this when the VM is not running, there is no effect (VMWare Workstation 12 Pro).

Comment: Thanks! Someone on SE who actually knows something... and of course, nobody replies to it in five long years, because nobody knows how to actually fix this.

Answer (score 3):

I can see how old this post is, but I noticed something relevant; it wasn't even Ubuntu. Apparently "Shared folders" must be enabled prior to installing `open-vm-tools` - also had `open-vm-tools-desktop` already installed and nothing worked. Reinstalling both packages does the job, seemingly when shared folder were enabled; this works instantly. With `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop --reinstall
```

Or with `dnf`:

```
sudo dnf reinstall open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

I'd assume that when enabling "shared folder" before the OS install, it should work out of the box.

Comment: slight correction to command: "sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop --reinstall".

Comment: @Todd Have corrected that; left the `dnf` syntax, because it may be useful.

Comment: Fans of my almost 200 different comments pointing out "solutions" that don't work at all, and exactly 0 that do, will be not at all surprised to know that, surprise, this does not work at all. Still no copy & paste.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the VMware Remote Console or Vsphere Client, then it wont work by just installing VMware tools.

You need to follow the steps described [here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/57122).

> To resolve this issue, first install or upgrade the VMware tools for
> the Windows/Linux virtual machine(VM). For more information see
> Installing and upgrading VMware Tools in vSphere.

[image]

- Click on Add Configuration Params three times to give three rows
- Fill in the Name and Value fields as mentioned below:

---

```
Name:                                 Value:
isolation.tools.copy.disable          FALSE
isolation.tools.paste.disable         FALSE
isolation.tools.setGUIOptions.enable  TRUE
```

Comment: I don't see "Add Configuration Params" in that window.

Comment: Maybe you need to shutdown the VM first.

Answer (score 0):

In my case in addition to bidirectional button activation, I had to do following steps:
On the terminal of guest virtual machine run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y make gcc perl
```

Now on virtual machine's main menu go: "Devices" -> "Insert Guest Additions CD image" -> wait popup to appear -> follow up installation steps -> once it's done go reboot
In my case it has resolved copy&paste issue

Comment: Perfect. This is the only answer that worked. Thanks !!!

Comment: No, no, and no. I already have the latest versions of those packages installed. This does... drum roll please... not work! Just like, apparently, literally 100% of the linux solutions on Stack Overflow, of which I have literally tried almost 200 at this point (I counted, it was 183 a few hours ago) with not so much as a single one of them ever solving the problem they claimed to solve.