# Reinstall vmware tools dependency problems

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, vmware

Suddenly my Ctr+c/Ctrl+v stopped working between host (windows) and client (ubuntu). According to [recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691585/copy-paste-and-dragdrop-not-working-in-vmware-machine-with-ubuntu) I was trying to reinstall VM tools.

Uninstall worked fine. But after restart install finished with error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
BuUding dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages wiU be installed:
libdumbnetl open-vm-tools zerofree
The following NEW packages will, be installed:
libdumbnetl open-vm- tools open-vm- tools-desktop zerofree
upgraded, 4 newly tnstaUed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/607 kB of archives.
fter this operation, 3,282 kB of additional., disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [V/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package libdumbnetl.
(Reading database ... 347756 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .. ./libdumbnetl_1.12-4buildl_arid64.deb
Unpacking libdumbnetl (1.12-4butldl)
Selecting previously unselected package open-vn-tools.
Preparing to unpack . . ./open-vm-tools_2%3a9.4.0-1280544-5ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb
Unpacking open-vm-tools (2:9.4.0-1280544-Subuntu6.2)
Selecting previously unselected package open-vn-tools-desktop.
Preparing to unpack . . ./open-vn-tools-desktop_2%3a9.4.6-1280544-5ubuntu6.2_and64
.deb
Unpacking open-vri-tools-desktop (2:9.4.0-1280544-Subuntu6.2)
Selecting previously unselected package zerofree.
Preparing to unpack . . ./zerofree_1.0.2-lubuntul_amd64.deb
Unpacking zerofree (1.0.2-lubuntul)
Processing triggers for rian-db (2.6.7.1-lubuntul)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.160.0-16)
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libdunbnetl (1.12-4buildl)
Setting up open-vm-tools (2:9.4.0-1280544-5ubuntu6.2)
* Starting open-vm daemon vntoolsd
i.nvoke-rc.d: initscrtpt open-vm-tools, action “start” failed. dpkg: error processing package open-vn-tools (- -configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of open-vm-tools-desktop:
open-vm-tools-desktop depends on open-vri-tools (= 2:9.4.0-1280544-5ubuntu6.2); however:
Package open-vm-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package open-vm-tools-desktop (- -configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro r from a previous failure.
Setting up zerofree (1.0.2-lubuntul)
Processing triggers for ltbc-bin (2.19-Oubuntu6.9)
Errors were encountered while processing:
open-vm-tools
open - vm- tools - desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkq returned an error code (1)
```

After one more restart I got error:

[image]

Ctr+c/Ctrl+v still not working. How to solve this problem?

UPD:

When system shutdowns I have messages:
[image]

UPD2

I did uninstall/install :

```
sudo apt-get remove open-vm-tools
sudo apt-get remove open-vm-tools-desktop
rm -r /etc/vmware-tools

sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

As result got resized window, but ctrl+c ctrl+v not working. And there are no errors on restart anymore