# Unable to drag & drop files to Lubuntu 16.10 guest in VMware

Tags: lubuntu, vmware, drag-and-drop

I am new here in this community. I have a problem with dragging and dropping files from host to Lubuntu 16.10 guest OS in VMware Worstation 12. Both copy-paste and drag n' drop from guest to host function is working except for drag n' drop from host to guest. I got VMware Tools installed and seems like nothing more I can do to fix this issue.

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/723929/661922) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/691589/661922) answers from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691585/copy-paste-and-dragdrop-not-working-in-vmware-machine-with-ubuntu?newreg=39a0e7df1b8544989ac9ef47178cd0e0) question but neither one worked for me.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually about installing the **VMware Tools** properly. So I've reinstall Lubuntu 16.10 today and my problem was fixed now.

> I'm leaving this answer in case someone has a similar issue.

The following steps fixed the problem for me (this is also useful for some beginners):

1. To install VMware Tools, click; `VM > Install VMware Tools` from the VMware menu bar while the virtual machine is running
2. Open Terminal and enter as *super user* to acquire root privilege; `sudo su` (requires the account's password)
3. Change directory to the mounted media; `cd "/media/username/VMware Tools"` (replace `username` with your account's username)
4. Copy the VMware Tools package from the media to the *temp* directory; `cp VMwareTools-version.tar.gz /tmp` (the `version` will be the version of the tools). *In any case, you can copy the package to wherever directory you prefer (E.g Desktop)*
5. Change directory to the temp directory; `cd /tmp` (or to the directory you choose to copy the package)
6. Using the `gunzip` command to uncompress the package; `gunzip VMwareTools-version.tar.gz`
7. Extract the package contents verbosely; `tar -xvf VMwareTools-version.tar.gz`
8. Change directory to the install files directory; `cd vmware-tools-distrib`
9. Run the install script; `./vmware-install.pl` and follow the instructions (the media will automatically unmounted when successfully installed)
10. Finally, reboot the OS to apply the changes

---

> **Notice:** If you're encountering errors when trying to drag and drop files from host to guest, then you can copy the file and paste it to the virtual machine directly (or JUST simply copy-paste the file(s))